# Selenium web_driver Javascript issue for closing the browser window

Tags: javascript, selenium

Actually two questions:

First One:  Is there anyway to start the browser on a specific URL(instead of about:blank) (I want to have a history length of 0 when starting on that URL?)

Second One:
I believe this is related to the above question

On the page I have the following:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function backAway(){
    if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer'){
       // under ie
       i = 0;
    } else {
    //firefox, chrome, etc..
       i = 1;
    }
    if (history.length>i)
        {
        // there appear to be items in the history property
        // this seems to happen with Firefox
        // If refferer exists, then do a back
        if (document.refferer){
            history.back();
        } else {
            window.close();
        }
    } else {
        window.close();
    }
    return false;
 }
 </script>


 <a href="" id="declineButton" title="Cancel" class="canc" onclick="backAway(); return     false;">Cancel</a>
```

python selenium stuff here:

```
 driver = webdriver.Firefox()
 driver.get(urlOAuth)
 declineButtons = driver.find_elements_by_id('declineButton'])
 declineButtons[0].click()
```

It successfully finds the declineButton, but the click appears to have no effect.
The page appears to function correctly when not using selenium.

Any thoughts? Suggestions? Questions?

Answer (score 0):

There is no Conecept Of Array here

Use the Statement driver.findElement(By.id("declineButton")).click() I am sure this will work.